# Using `title` with ScalaTags

Tags: scala, scalatags

The title tag is not working as expected with the ScalaTags library.

```
import scalatags.Text.all._

title("My Awesome Website")
```

How can I get this to work?

> Help docs/tutorials are conveniently missing the ubiquitous title tag.  I hope the dev fixes this..
>
> https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags

Not Working as Expected:

If you look at how tags such as `link`, `script`, `head`, `html` are used the `title` tag should work the same.

For some reason the dev chose to make this tag `ConcreteHtmlTag[Nothing]` rather than the former tag's type `ConcreteHtmlTag[String]`.  Its also strange that this tag is in the `Tags2` package rather than `Tags`, it *is* a commonly used tag after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one seems to work:

```
scala> scalatags.Text.tags2.title("test")
res7: scalatags.Text.TypedTag[Nothing] = <title>test</title>
```

It seems like the `title` in `scalatags.Text.all` is a tag attribute (`scalatags.generic.Attr`) and not a `TypedTag`. Whether or not this is misplaced or not (or should be `TypedTag[String]`), I don't know. Perhaps it's just a symbol collision in your code.

An explicit `import scalatags.Text.tags2.title` ought to help.

Comment: I see the difference now.  This would imply a symbol collision between the two `title` objects - the dev should probably rename the `title` attribute to something else like he did for `class` to `cls`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of importing `all`, there are alternate imports you can use.

```
import scalatags.Text.short._
import scalatags.Text.tags2._

html(
  head(
    title("Your Title Here")
  ),
  body(

  )
)
```

More examples are in [Managing Imports](http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/#ManagingImports) section in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
import scalatags.Text.all.{title=>titleAttr,_}
import scalatags.Text.tags2.title
```

If you are using scalatra, you will also want to protect head

```
import scalatags.Text.all.{head=>headTag, title=>titleAttr,_}
import scalatags.Text.tags2.title
```